# Error Code using $Ajax, phpjson and sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: ajax

I have code like this in dataset.php

```
    $query = "SELECT A,B,C from Table ";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($link2,$query);     
                $data = array();
                while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
                {

                    $data['data'][]= array (
                                    'kodeLang'      => $row['A'],
                                    'nama_lang'     => $row['B'],
                                    'address'       => $row['C']

                );
                }
echo json_encode($data);
```

and , i want to load the dataset.php in index.php with code like this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'dataset.php', //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
                data: '',         
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",,
                success: function(data){          
                     alert(data);

                     $("#atotal td#aTotal").html(data[0]['kodeLang']);
                },
                error : function (jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){
                    $('#errorr').fadeIn(1000).show();
                }

            });
           event.preventDefault();


    });
    </script>
```

But when i using alert(data) in index.php, there's no alert. Is there any missed with my code ?

Trims

Comment: i have solved by my self,

Answer (score 0):

I have answer by my self, the proble about the array. I modified the file in index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


             $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'dataset.php',
                data: '',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response){                   
                         $("#atotal td#aTotal").html(response.data[0].A);
                },
                error : function (jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){
                    $('#errorr').fadeIn(1000).show();
                }
            });
           event.preventDefault();

    });

    </script>
```